# Запустить один python unittest для двух аналогичных классов

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, юнит-тесты

Не могу разобраться с тестированием в Python. Конкретнее -- тестирование бэкэнда на django. 
Задача такова. Есть класс A с методами doAA и doBB.
Соответственно есть тест-класс TestA(unittest.TestCase), содержащий тесты testDoAA и testDoBB.

Всё замечательно и всё устраивает, но до тех пор, пока не появляется клас B, набор методов которого идентичен классу A.

То есть B и A выполняют одни задачи немного по-разному. Писать ещё один класс, типа TestB, с копированием туда всего из TestA видется варварским и неправильным путём.

Подскажите, как можно один раз описав тест запустить его дважды для двух аналогичных классов? и простите за терминологические и прочие ошибки, для меня пайтон язык новый и до боли непривычный.

p.s.: Хотел было назвать вопрос так: "Запустить python unittest для интерфейса, а не для класса", но это не совсем так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса TestCase есть метод `setUp`, который позволяет задать общие данные для всех методов, это решает часть проблем.

> Писать ещё один класс, типа TestB, с копированием туда всего из TestA
>   видется варварским и неправильным путём.

Вы же с ООП работаете. Тут точно так же как и в ваших классах А и Б необходимо выносить общий функционал в класс выше (генерализация). У вас ведь в классах код не повторяется, я так думаю? Вот и при тестировании он повторятся не должен благодаря тем же самым приёмам.

Comment: Да! Спасибо!
В итоге унаследовал от основного TestCase два класса TestA и TestB, у каждого из которых в setUp уже задаю с экземпляром какого из наследников базового для A и B класса вести работу.